# GWT can not deploy to the remote tomcat with http 404 and page not found info as return

Tags: gwt, tomcat, http-status-code-404, rpc

remote:fedora 15 with jdk+tomcat (vmware)
local:win7 with jdk+tomcat(my notebook)

Several days before,I create a default GWT project using Eclipse google plugin and deploy it to "remote" successfully,it works fine!And now I create a new one on the same way.IE gave me a http 404,page not found infos as a return.I'm sure I do nothing to the project file except creating it.And the former still works fine,the latter doesn't work yet.The only difference between them is the dir which contain the war files.
I try solving it by many ways.Here are some useful result:
I can almost confirm the block bellow(in web.xml) cause the problem

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>gwtref/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

when I change servlet-class content to anything (even wrong),the http 404 error would disapear.I can get the right page,as you can imagin,rpc doesn't work for servlet-class'content being changed!
I don't know how it happens,I do nothing except time going by!
I also deploy the latter to tomcat installed on my notebook.It works fine!God!What a amazing problem!I'm a newer to web application development with java.Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but here I go.

In general if you get a runtime error while starting the war in a servlet container the whole war will be marked as unavailable. You are saying that if you remove the servlet the 404 goes away, which makes me believe that the class com.test.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl is not insde your war file (some typo?).

Take a look into WEB-INF/classes/ if its there. If not you got your error...

Comment: thks Daniel,GreetingServiceImpl is existed at the place it should be!But I don't know how to make the tomcat know where the GreetingServiceImpl is.............I added some info above you answer!

Comment: can you post your full tomcat log from startup?

Comment: I think I got the result!The curious scene was caused by JDK.The version on "local" is different from the "remote".I take a look into the log of tomcat,it shows me the reason.I made a silly mistake---the version of JDK should be identical on both the local and remote.....^!^ thanks again for your warming-heart!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and following helped me to fix it:

1. Build jar from the src folder of the project (Export the jar into /war/Web-Inf/lib/(name_of_jar).jar
2. Build a war file from your war folder and deploy it on tomcat (I used Ant Build to make war)

```
<target name="default" depends="buildwar,deploy"></target>

<target name="buildwar">
    <war basedir="war" destfile="(Some Name).war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </webinf>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <copy file="(Some Name).war" todir="." />
</target>
```